# Difference between g+w and 775 linux

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

Sorry if this is a really simple question, been trying to read up on all this stuff.
I know there could be a difference maybe in reading and writing, so I guess to specify the question,

Should doing a chmod 775 be inclusive and give more permissions to owner and group. Is there anything gained by specifically giving group writing with g+w?
How about chmod 2775? I have been reading about this and not sure what the 2 adds. I saw setuid and stuff, but if the owner:group is already the correct owner:group and you change to 775, what is 2775 adding?

On ls -l, there is already drwxrwxr-x present, but users of a group can't write to a folder? Does this seem right?

Answer (score 2):

The numeric and the character way of giving perms produce the same result.  The numeric is shorter and I use it because I am used to it.  Use whichever is comfortable for you.

Do not give special perms (like suid, sgid) unless you have a specific reason to do so.  We rarely see anything besides 3 digit perms (700, 644, 775, etc).

http://www.zzee.com/solutions/unix-permissions.shtml#setuid is a nice page on all of this.

Answer (score 1):

Doing `chmod 775` explicitly sets each of the 12 bits (setuid, setgid, sticky, and read, write, execute for each of owner, group and others) to a specific value based on the given numeric value.

The symbolic method allows you to individually set or unset specific bits - `chmod g+w` takes the existing permissions, specifically sets the group write bit, and writes the modified value back. You can also use `-` to unset a bit or `=` to set a particular group (e.g. `g=r` will set the read bit and clear both the write and execute bit for the group). This method gives you more fine-grained control over the different permissions without having to think about the correct complete octal value for a particular set of permissions you want to achieve.